# Consolidate records in T-SQL where the difference between end time of the current record and start time of the next record is less than x minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to consolidate records based on a time gap of 5 minutes between the current row-end date and the next row start date. How can I achieve this T-SQL?

Before Consolidation, the table is like below -

```
+---------+------------------+------------------+
| EventId |    StartTime     |     EndTime      |
+---------+------------------+------------------+
|       1 | 2020-11-05 10:05 | 2020-11-05 10:08 |
|       2 | 2020-11-05 10:15 | 2020-11-05 10:17 |
|       3 | 2020-11-05 10:20 | 2020-11-05 10:24 |
|       4 | 2020-11-05 10:25 | 2020-11-05 10:30 |
|       5 | 2020-11-05 10:40 | 2020-11-05 10:48 |
|       6 | 2020-11-05 10:58 | 2020-11-05 11:05 |
+---------+------------------+------------------+
```

It should look like below after consolidation -

```
| Consolidated StartTime | Consolidated EndTime |
|------------------------|----------------------|
| 2020-11-05 10:05       | 2020-11-05 10:08     |
| 2020-11-05 10:15       | 2020-11-05 10:30     |
| 2020-11-05 10:40       | 2020-11-05 10:48     |
| 2020-11-05 10:58       | 2020-11-05 11:05     |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  For this problem, use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select min(starttime), max(endtime)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_endtime >= dateadd(minute, 5, starttime) then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (order by eventid) as island_num
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(endtime) over (order by eventid) as prev_endtime
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by island_num;
```

The `lag()` gets the previous `endtime` for comparison.  The middle query determines when a new "island" starts.  This occurs when there is more than 5 minutes between the previous `endtime` and current `starttime`.  The outer query then aggregates to get the final result.